# vercel cli installation problem in windows

Tags: vercel

i have installed vercel globally but whenever i give `vercel login or vercel` command in terminal it's show following error.. already googled this problem but no solution found.

```
 vercel : The term 'vercel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
    a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    At line:1 char:1
    + vercel login
    + ~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vercel:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem when I tried to install vercel CLI using yarn.
Posting this to save others some time.

Tried running it through Visual Code and through powershell.
Tried running it global with vercel@latest

What DID work was:
npm install -g vercel on powershell with administrator privileges on.

(Yarn still didn't work in that scenario)
I also was not in the base directory

Why? Honestly, I am not sure. I just wanted to post in the hope that this saves someone else some time.